# Сравнение элементов в контейнерном классе array

Tags: c++, массивы, stl, сравнение

Проблема следующая, есть класс Person с именем и возрастом. Я создаю 2 контейнера  array, забивая их какими-то экземплярами, и позже хочу сравнить эти контейнеры, на что получаю ошибку. Оператор сравнения перегрузил, а на ютубе посмотрел, что мол перегрузки будет достаточно для сравнения

Серьезность Код Описание    Проект  Файл    Строка  Состояние подавления
Ошибка  C2672   "operator __surrogate_func": не найдена соответствующая перегруженная функция   prikl_programming   c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.16.27023\include\xutility    3084

```
`#include <iostream>
 #include <string>
 #include <list>
 using namespace std;

 class Person {
 public:
 Person(int age, string name) {
    this->age = age;
    this->name = name;
 }
 Person() {
    age = 0;
    name = "null";
 }

 bool operator==(const Person& p) {
    if (this->age == p.age && this->name == p.name)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
 }

 private:
 int age;
 string name;

 friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Person& p);      
 };

 int main() {

 list<Person> l = { Person(1, ""), Person(2, ""), Person(3, "") };
 list<Person> l2 = { Person(2, ""), Person(2, ""), Person(3, "") };

 bool flag = (l == l2);
введите сюда код
 system("pause");
 return 0;
 }

 ostream & operator<<(ostream & os, const Person & p)
 {
 cout << p.age << " " << p.name;
 return os;
 }`
```

Comment: `const` квалификатор в операторе пропущен `bool operator==(const Person& p) const`. А лучше будет вынести функцию сравнения наружу.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Попробуйте дать компилятору понять, что ваше сравнение не будет ничего менять в сравниваемых объектах - что это константная функция-член:

```
    bool operator==(const Person& p) const {
        if (this->age == p.age && this->name == p.name)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
```

(обратите внимание на второй `const` в первой строке).

Comment: Да, спасибо это помогло! Первый раз правда с таким встречаюсь

Answer (score 2):

А давайте немного обсудим как лучше строить подобный код.

1. Нужно иметь возможность знать имя  или возраст личности, а также придать им новые значения  поэтому
   проще эти поля сделать открытыми. И, так как тип не имеет других полей, то он легко сделается обычной структурой, не имеющей закрытых данных.
2. Конструктор по умолчанию будет означать, что нам неизвестно имя и
   возраст личности. Он может быть определен посредством вызова
   имеющегося конструктора с конкретными аргументами.
3. Сама личность не должна иметь функциональность сравнения  себя с
   другой личностью. Такие функции лучше вынести за класс.

Исходя из этих соображений напишем улучшенный код, где, кстати, не происходят лишные копировния строк и дальнейшее присваивание в конструкторе (как в вашем случаи):

```
struct Person {
    int age{};
    string name;
    Person(const int age, const string& name) :  age(age), name(name) {}
    Person() : Person(0, "unknown") {}
};

inline bool operator ==(const Person& p1, const Person& p2)
{
    return  p1.age == p2.age && p1.name == p2.name;
}
int main() {    
    list<Person> l = { Person(1, ""), Person(2, ""), Person(3, "") };
    list<Person> l2 = { Person(2, ""), Person(2, ""), Person(3, "") };
    bool flag = (l == l2);
    //...       
}
```

Такой код нагляднее показывает наши намерения и читабельней...

Comment: 1. Эх, вот бы мне константный возраст в жизни..., 2. А вдруг нужно использовать какую-то логику при установке или получения значения? Для этого понадобиться кроить класс и добавлять геттеры, а потом по всей программе искать места, где было обращение к полям. Лучше сделать с геттерами\сеттерами сразу. В Java даже правило такое есть. Доступ к любому полю только через геттер\сеттер, точнее это даже правило ООП. 3. Зачем нам такой Person?

Comment: @Drawn Raccoon , по вашей логике  структуры простых данных вообше не должны существовать... В жизни  и в науке нет правил, которые нужно соблюдать абсолютно во всех случаях. Каждое решение исходит из целесообразности решения данной задачи.  Решение также зависит от абстракции класса. Изменять состояне обьекта с помощью сеттеров или  без них, имея открытые члены, никак не  изменит сложность ваших поисков где в программе было обращение к ним.  В науке, особенно в программировании на C++ нет однозначных решений. Чаще не имеет смысла иметь закрытые члены и геттеры с сеттерами, чем имеет...

Comment: Спасибо, буду учиться...